# Have you had user specific bugs with Unity builds that you have sent out

Tags: unity-game-engine, build, playmaker

I have a build which I send out to players and 50% of them get different unique bugs, where Stats reset, Array values match up differently, Certain attributes increase by zero.

This only seems exclusive to their computers and are all very different.
I've attempt sleep nights trying to replicate these bugs on multiple computers, but it I cannot replicate it.

The other 50% of players (Although I don't the actual ratio)
The build works fine, all the bugs and issues that occurs are ones that I know about and easily fix.

I'm desperate to know what's going here, if its something in player settings like changing .NET 2.0 to 4.0 or something like that, but honestly I'm not so well experienced in that area.

Playmaker is mixed into the project for arrays and simpler things, but I've scoured the forums and I can't find anything related to that.

Maybe I need to upgrade my version of unity?
I'm on Unity 2020.1.1f1 Personal, if that has anything to do with how the game builds, but at this point I'm just throwing punch's in the dark.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I also use Playmaker and I've recently experienced a similar bug.

It turns out different CultureSettings on users were causing the issue.

Try this:

*using System.Globalization;*

and

*CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;*

Wish you a great weekend :)